# Find unique set of strings in vector where vector elements can be multiple strings

Tags: r

I have a series of batch records that are labeled sequentially.  Sometimes batches overlap.

```
x <- c("1","1","1/2","2","3","4","5/4","5")
> data.frame(x)
    x
1   1
2   1
3 1/2
4   2
5   3
6   4
7 5/4
8   5
```

I want to find the set of batches that are not overlapping and label those periods.  Batch "1/2" includes both "1" and "2" so it is not unique.  When batch = "3" that is not contained in any previous batches, so it starts a new period. I'm having difficulty dealing with the combined batches, otherwise this would be straightforward. The result of this would be:

```
    x period
1   1      1
2   1      1
3 1/2      1
4   2      1
5   3      2
6   4      3
7 5/4      3
8   5      3
```

My experience is in more functional programming paradigms, so I know the way I did this is very un-R.  I'm looking for the way to do this in R that is clean and simple.  Any help is appreciated.

Here's my un-R code that works, but is super clunky and not extensible.

```
x <- c("1","1","1/2","2","3","4","5/4","5")

p <- 1 #period number
temp <- NULL #temp variable for storing cases of x (batches)
temp[1] <- x[1]
period <- NULL
rl <- 0 #length to repeat period

for (i in 1:length(x)){

    #check for "/", split and add to temp
    if (grepl("/", x[i])){
        z <- strsplit(x[i], "/") #split character
        z <- unlist(z) #convert to vector
        temp <- c(temp, z, x[i]) #add to temp vector for comparison
    }

    #check if x in temp
    if(x[i] %in% temp){
        temp <- append(temp, x[i]) #add to search vector
        rl <- rl + 1 #increase length
    } else {
        period <- append(period, rep(p, rl)) #add to period vector
        p <- p + 1 #increase period count
        temp <- NULL #reset
        rl <- 1 #reset
    }
}

#add last batch

rl <- length(x) - length(period)
period <- append(period, rep(p,rl))

df <- data.frame(x,period)

> df
    x period
1   1      1
2   1      1
3 1/2      1
4   2      1
5   3      2
6   4      3
7 5/4      3
8   5      3
```

Comment: so because batch 1/2 contains 1 & 2, 2 is no longer a unique batch? Similar to why 5 is not considered a unique batch?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  1/2 contains parts of 1 and 2.  Same for 5/4.

Comment: are there instances when a batch includes two parts but neither has appeared before?

Comment: I suppose that could be possible, but given the source of my data, it should not happen.  So for the purposes of this example, I would say no, a batch will not include two parts where neither has appeared before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit shorter:

```
x <- c("1","1","1/2","2","3","4","5/4","5")
x<-data.frame(x=x, period=-1, stringsAsFactors = F)
period=0
prevBatch=-1
for (i in 1:nrow(x))
{
   spl=unlist(strsplit(x$x[i], "/"))
   currentBatch=min(spl)
   if (currentBatch<prevBatch) { stop("Error in sequence") }
   if (currentBatch>prevBatch)
      period=period+1;

   x$period[i]=period;

   prevBatch=max(spl)
}
x
```

Answer (score 2):

R has functional paradigm influences, so you can solve this with `Map` and `Reduce`. Note that this solution follows your approach in unioning seen values. A simpler approach is possible if you assume batch numbers are consecutive, as they are in your example.

```
x <- c("1","1","1/2","2","3","4","5/4","5")
s<-strsplit(x,"/")
r<-Reduce(union,s,init=list(),acc=TRUE)
p<-cumsum(Map(function(x,y) length(intersect(x,y))==0,s,r[-length(r)]))

data.frame(x,period=p)
```

```
    x period
1   1      1
2   1      1
3 1/2      1
4   2      1
5   3      2
6   4      3
7 5/4      3
8   5      3
```

What this does is first calculate a cumulative union of seen values. Then, it maps across this to determine the places where none of the current values have been seen before. (Alternatively, this second step could be included within the reduce, but this would be wordier without support for destructuring.) The cumulative sum provides the "period" numbers based on the number of times the intersections have come up empty.

If you do make the assumption that the batch numbers are consecutive then you can do the following instead

```
x <- c("1","1","1/2","2","3","4","5/4","5")
s<-strsplit(x,"/")
n<-mapply(function(x) range(as.numeric(x)),s)
p<-cumsum(c(1,n[1,-1]>n[2,-ncol(n)]))

data.frame(x,period=p)
```

For the same result (not repeated here).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still trying to understand this solution (although I see by running it that it works).  What does `acc = TRUE` do in Reduce?  Reduce with `union` appears to create a list of unique groupings.  In that case, why did the 1/2 get split?  This confuses me because then wouldn't the Map step be looking for groupings that didn't exist in the original `x`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a twist on the original that uses `tidyr` to split the data into two columns so it's easier to use:

```
# sample data
x <- c("1","1","1/2","2","3","4","5/4","5")
df <- data.frame(x)

library(tidyr)
# separate x into two columns, with second NA if only one number
df <- separate(df, x, c('x1', 'x2'), sep = '/', remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)
```

Now `df` looks like:

```
> df
    x x1 x2
1   1  1 NA
2   1  1 NA
3 1/2  1  2
4   2  2 NA
5   3  3 NA
6   4  4 NA
7 5/4  5  4
8   5  5 NA
```

Now the loop can be a lot simpler:

```
period <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  period <- c(period,
              # test if either x1 or x2 of row i are in any x1 or x2 above it
              ifelse(any(df[i, 2:3] %in% unlist(df[1:(i-1),2:3])), 
                     period[i],        # if so, repeat the terminal value
                     period[i] + 1))   # else append the terminal value + 1
}

# rebuild df with x and period, which loses its extra initializing value here 
df <- data.frame(x = df$x, period = period[2:length(period)])
```

The resulting `df`:

```
> df
    x period
1   1      1
2   1      1
3 1/2      1
4   2      1
5   3      2
6   4      3
7 5/4      3
8   5      3
```